# Map keeps coming back to the base location

Tags: ios

I am trying to add annotations to multiple locations on the Map. I am  using Simulator with iPhone 6 selected as the Device. However when I drag the map to other locations in order to add annotations, it keeps coming back to the base location.i.e the original location the simulator displayed at the launch ( note: I have imported CoreLocation, add added NSLocationAlways and WheninUse to the info.plist).

How do I let it stay at the location I drag the map to ?

Here is the code...

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var theMap: MKMapView!

    var locManager =  CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locManager.delegate = self
        locManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressed:")
        longPress.minimumPressDuration = 2
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

    }

    func longPressed(theGesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        if theGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
            print("recognised")

            let touchPoint = theGesture.locationInView(self.theMap)
            let convertedTouchPoint = theMap.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.theMap)

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = "Place 1"
            annotation.subtitle = "Description Place 1"
            annotation.coordinate = convertedTouchPoint

            theMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let userLocation = locations[0]

        let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

        let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        let longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: longDelta)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: span)
        theMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    }


}
```

Comment: You're still listening for location updates so every time the location manager sends an update `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` gets called and sets the region on your map back to the current location

Comment: so how do I keep both the options ? 1. keep getting the user location 2. have the ability to browse across different locations ?

Comment: You could have some `shouldFollowUserLocation` state variable that starts as `true` and set it to `false` if the user pans the map, then have a button over the map that sets it back to `true` and moves the map to the current location again.  Then in the `didUpdateLocations` callback only set the region if the state variable is `true`

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that, with the Simulator selected , navigate to Debug--> Location and Select 'None'. This fixed the issue. I can now drag to different locations without getting back to the base location.

Comment: This doesn't fix anything, it just hides the issue because it stops the device from getting location updates.  Once you run it on a real device that has a functioning gps it will start doing the same thing again.